# I keep getting this error: Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r

[image]

```
#task 1
mydata <- read.csv("admit.(1)")
str(mydata)
```

It keeps giving me an error

```
> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:  
In file(file, "rt") :    
  cannot open file 'admit.(1)': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Does your file have an extension e.g. `read.csv("admit.(1).csv")` .  Do you need a full path to the file?

Comment: ps please don't add images of code :https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors .

Comment: (1) It appears as if the filename is `admit (1).csv`, not `admit.(1)` or `admit.(1).csv`. Filenames are specific and need to match (windows case-insensitive notwithstanding). (2) It also appears as if you already read in your data a few lines up, using `\`admit.(1)\` <- read.csv("C:/Users/sanan/Downloads/admit (1).csv")`, and it is showing in your environment (top-right pane), why are you trying to `read.csv("admit.(1)")` as if you need to `read.csv` an object already in R? Just use `\`admit.(1)\`` on the console (with backticks) to access its contents. You might want to rename it for ease.